# Semantics, standards and using the "lang" attribute for source code in markup

Tags: html, standards, web-standards, semantic-markup

I haven't been able to find authorative explanations, microformats or guidelines for the following, so I'm throwing it open. If I've missed something, speak up!

Let's say you have an HTML page that includes an example of some programming source code inside a `<pre>` element:

```
<pre>
    # code...
</pre>
```

(*Update: As Pekka points out below, `<code>` might be better than `<pre>` but the following examples/discussion can apply to both. And as Brian Campbell points out* both *elements should of course be used for preformatted code*)

#### Now: How do you – in a semantically correct and spec compliant way – declare the *programming language* of the `<pre>` block's contents?

This would be useful information to include in the markup in a semantically consistent way.

The obvious choice, from a semantic standpoint, would be to use the `lang` attribute:

```
<pre lang="ruby">
```

**But** according to the [HTML 4 spec, section 8.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#langcodes):

> The lang attribute's value is a language code that identifies a *natural* language [...] Computer languages are explicitly *excluded* from language codes.

(emphasis mine)

And besides, "ruby" isn't a standard language code anyway.

The spec does allow for adding "experimental" or "private use" codes using the `x` primary tag. The example from the spec is `lang="x-klingon"`.

In theory, you could use `x-ruby`, `x-java` and so forth to declare the programming languge contained in the `<pre>` block – except that it seems the spec frowns upon using the `lang` attribute for programming languages in general.

The [HTML 5 spec on the topic](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) doesn't make matters any clearer. The spec itself doesn't explicitly mention "natural" vs "programming" languages. Instead it refers the reader to [BCP 47](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), which states (again):

> Language tags are used to help identify languages [...] but excludes languages not intended primarily for human communication, such as programming languages.

However, it goes on to mention (in section 4.1, page 56) the `zxx` primary language subtag, which:

> identifies content for which a language classification is inappropriate or does not apply.  Some examples might include instrumental or electronic music [...] or *programming source code*.

(emphasis mine)

Again, the spec seems to contradict itself, but it opens up the possiblilty of using `zxx-x-ruby` (or similar) as a fully spec-compliant way of both declaring something to be written in *a* language (just not a human one) *and* declaring the specific (non-human) language involved.

#### So, is there any semblance of a standard/microformat/microsyntax/gentleman's agreement/*anything* on what to do?

Personally, I like `zxx-x-ruby` as its the most complete. `x-ruby` by itself is shorter and neater of course, but unless I'm mistaken, the `<pre>` block would still inherit the primary language of its parent (e.g. `en` or `fr` or similar).

---

#### Addendum:

As Pekka mentions below, the `<code>` tag would probably be more appropriate, and semantically it'd be *very* neat to simply say `<code lang="...">`. However, the `<code>` tag is also an inline element, and I was initially thinking only of longer runs of source code, i.e. declaring the language for all `<code>` elements contained in block-level `<pre>` elements.

Luckily, the `lang` attribute is global and can be applied to either element, so either one would work.

Second: I accidentally typed "zzx" *everywhere* instead of the correct "zxx"! It's *one* 'z', *two* 'x's. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: BCP 47 mentions `zxx` not `zzx` for non-linguistic content.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I know, I realized my mistake and fixed it just about the same time your were writing your comment :)

Comment: Why would the `pre` block still inherit the primary language? `@lang specifies the language for the element's contents and text attributes` from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes seems to disagree and `x-` seems perfectly fitting as it's for `Non-linguistic` languages, including `machine-readable data` (which includes programs, as programs are data for turing machines).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To answer this question, we should look at two things; any potentially relevant specifications, and what is actually done in the real world. You've already mentioned what the relevant specifications have said on the `lang` attribute; it is generally used for indicating the human language of the content referenced, not the programming language. While BCP 47 mentions the `zxx` tag for non-linguistic content, I don't believe that it is really appropriate to use the `lang` attribute and `zxx` subtag for specifying the programming language. The reason is that most source code does actually have some linguistic content, which is in a natural language; comments, variable names, strings, and the like. The `lang` attribute should probably be used to indicate these, especially in cases like use of CJK characters where font selection might be based on the `lang` attribute. The programming language contained within a code example is really orthogonal to the human language contained within it; conflating the two will likely lead to confusion, not clarity.

So, let's check the specs for an alternative to the `lang` attribute. As Pekka points out in another answer, the `<code>` element is more semantically meaningful for marking up source code than the `<pre>` element, so let's check there. According to the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element):

> The `code` element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be an XML element name, a filename, a computer program, or any other string that a computer would recognize.
>
> Although there is no formal way to indicate the language of computer code being marked up, authors who wish to mark `code` elements with the language used, e.g. so that syntax highlighting scripts can use the right rules, may do so by adding a class prefixed with "`language-`" to the element.
>
> ...
>
> > The following example shows how a block of code could be marked up using the pre and code elements.
> >
> > ```
> > <pre><code class="language-pascal">var i: Integer;
> > begin
> >    i := 1;
> > end.</code></pre>
> > ```
> >
> > A class is used in that example to indicate the language used.

Now, this isn't a formal specification, just an informal recommendation for how you could use a class to indicate the language represented. The example also shows how to use both a `<pre>` tag and `<code>` tag to mark up a block of code.

We can look elsewhere for any sort of standards, but I haven't found any; there are no microformats for code formatting, and I haven't found any other specs that mention it. So, we move on to what people actually do. The best way to discover this is to look at what HTML syntax highlighting libraries do, since they are the main producers and consumers of code embedded in web pages in which the language actually matters.

There are two main types of HTML syntax highlighters; those that run on the server or offline, in Ruby or Python or PHP, and produce static HTML and CSS to be displayed by the browser, and those written in JavaScript, which find and highlight `<pre>` or `<code>` elements on the client side. The second category is more interesting, as they need to detect the language from the HTML provided to them; in the first category, you usually specify the language manually through the API or through some mechanism specific to your wiki, blog, or CMS syntax, and so there is no actual consumer of any language information that might be embedded in the HTML. We'll take a look at both categories for the sake of completeness.

For JavaScript syntax highlighters, I've found the following, with examples of their syntax for specifying a code block and its language:

- [SyntaxHighligher](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/): `<pre class="brush: html">...</pre>`. Appears to completely ignore how `class` should be used by introducing its own syntax for `class` attributes based on CSS syntax with the `brush` keyword used to indicate the language. Also has an option for using the `<script>` tag, to make it easier to copy and paste code in without having to escape `<`, using the same `class` syntax.
- [Highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/): `<pre><code class="html">...</code></pre>` or `class="language-html"` or the same on `<pre>`. This gives you several options, one of which corresponds to the recommendation in the HTML5 spec, the other simply uses the bare language name as the class name.
- [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/): `<pre class="sh_html">...</pre>`. Uses its own prefix for language names in the class, and only works on `<pre>`, not other elements.
- [beautyOfCode](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/): `<pre class="code"><code class="html">...</code></pre>`. Based on SyntaxHighlighter, but with a somewhat less weird syntax. Requires a the `<pre>` tag with class `code` and the `code` tag with a class indicating the language.
- [Chili](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/): `<code class="html">...</code>`. Uses just the `<code>` tag, and uses the bare language as a class name.
- [Lighter.js](http://pradador.com/code/lighterjs/): `<pre class="html">...</code>`. Uses the bare language as a class name. You select the elements it will apply to using the API, but the example demonstrates it on `<pre>` tags.
- [DlHighlight](http://mihai.bazon.net/projects/javascript-syntax-highlighting-engine): `<pre name="code" class="html">...</pre>`. Uses the bare language as a class name. You choose via the API what type of element to highlight (the example used `pre`) and the value of the `name` attribute to look for to indicate that you want syntax highlighting. I believe that this is an abuse of the `name` attribute.
- [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/): `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">`. Uses class names prefixed with `lang-` to specify the language, and the class `prettyprint` to indicate that you want syntax highlighting. The language class is optional; it will try to auto-detect the language if not specified.
- [JUSH](http://jush.sourceforge.net/): `<code class="jush-html">...</code>` or `<code class="language-html">...</code>`. Uses the `code` tag, with languages in a class prefixed by `jush-` or `language-`.
- [Rainbow](https://craig.is/making/rainbows): `<pre><code data-language="javascript">...</code></pre>` uses the custom attribute `data-language`, applied to either a `<code>` element, or a `<pre>` element, in order to support sites like Tumblr which strip out `<code>` elements.
- [Prism](http://prismjs.com/): `<pre><code class="language-css">...</code></pre>` follows the HTML5 spec for nested `<pre>` and `<code>`, and the recommendation for the class name.

For server-based and offline syntax highlighters, the majority ([CodeRay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/), [UltraViolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/), [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), [Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html)) do not embed any language information in the HTML they output at all. [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is the only one I found that embeds the language, as `<pre class="html">...</pre>`, a `<pre>` tag with a bare language name as the class.

Out of that list, there seems to be no real consensus. The most popular option is just using the bare language name as a class. The next most popular is using some form of prefixed language name, either prefixed by the library name, `lang-`, or `language-`. There are a few that have their own strange conventions, or don't specify the language in the HTML at all.

While the only thing common enough to be a de-facto standard is using the bare language name as a class, I would recommend going with what the HTML5 spec recommends, a class name of `language-` followed by the name of the language. This is supported by a few of the syntax highlighters, the rest could probably be easily modified to support it. It is less ambiguous and less likely to conflict with other classes than just the bare language name as a class. And, even if not formally specified, it is at least mentioned in a spec.

I would also use the `<code>` tag to indicate source code, either bare or embedded in a `<pre>` tag; the combination of a `<code>` tag and `language-` prefixed class can be used to indicate that you have source code in a particular language, and could be used to indicate you want it to be highlighted, and is clearer and better matches the semantics of the elements than some of the other indicators used by syntax highlighting libraries. For cases in which a `<code>` tag can't be used, such as embedding in sites that accept only a limited HTML subset like Tumblr, just using the `<pre>` tag with the same class convention is probably best.

**edit to add**: The [CommonMark specification](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.20/), which attempts to standardize Markdown so that implementations can be interoperable, producing the same HTML given the same input, has also adopted this suggested convention. It adds [fenced code blocks](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.20/#fenced-code-blocks) to Markdown, surrounded with ```` ``` ```` or `~~~`, which can be easier to use than indentation based code blocks. Immediately following the opening fence can be an [info string](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.20/#info-string), which is defined as:

> An info string can be provided after the opening code fence. Opening and closing spaces will be stripped, and the first word, prefixed with `language-`, is used as the value for the `class` attribute of the `code` element within the enclosing `pre` element.

It can be instructive also the check what actual implementations do. [Trying out a fenced code block on Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%60%60%60python%0Adef+foo%28%29%3A%0A++++print+%22Hello%22%0A%60%60%60) shows that of those implementations that support fenced code blocks (not all do as it's an extension to the original Markdown), we see the following breakdown:

- showdown, blakfriday, haskell markdown: `<pre><code class="python">...</code></pre>`
- marked: `<pre><code class="lang-python">...</code></pre>`
- commonmark, parsedown, cebe/markdown: `<pre><code class="language-python">...</code></pre>`
- cheapskate, minima: `<pre class="python">...</pre>`
- pandoc: `<div class="sourceCode"><pre class="sourceCode python"><code class="sourceCode python">...</code></pre></div>` (quite the overkill)
- Maruku: `<pre class="python"><code class="python">...</code></pre>`

Looking at other document markup languages that convert to HTML and have some understanding of code blocks:

- AsciiDoc: `<pre>...</pre>`; simply uses Pygments to highlight and does not include language information in the HTML.
- `rst2html` gave me `<pre class="code python literal-block">...</pre>`, highlighted with Pygments.
- Sphinx: `<div class="highlight-python"><div class="highlight"><pre>...</pre></div></div>`, also highlighted with Pygments.

So, overall, fairly large diversity in choices by different projects, but there does seem to be some movement towards standardizing on `<pre><code class="language-python">...</code></pre>`.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better or more complete answer – thank you! Your point about source code containing natural language is well taken. From that point of view, the `zxx` tag is, I presume, meant for code that's only readable for a computer (e.g. compiled code). Using class names instead would also be the solution I'd choose in lieu of something "better" (which is what I'd hoped the `zxx` tag presented). Lastly, despite my question's focus on `<pre>`, the `<code>` element would of course be used too, as in the HTML 5 specification's example.  
Thank you again!

Comment: One thing I'm still curious about: Disregarding the `zxx` tag, could you still use `lang="x-ruby"`? My understanding is that it would be "correct" althought just as informal as using class names, as it'd be a private (`x`) tag

Comment: @Flambino I think that has the same problem as `zxx`; the `lang` tag, and BCP 47 language codes, are intended for representing natural language, not programming language. HTML 4 states this explicitly, HTML5 references BCP 47, which says: "Language tags are used to help identify languages, whether spoken, written, signed, or otherwise signaled, for the purpose of communication.  This includes constructed and artificial languages but excludes languages not intended primarily for human communication, such as programming languages."

Comment: @Flambino Yeah, I think that `zxx` is a tag that is mostly useful for cases in which a language tag is required, but there is no discernable human language in the content, such as an image with no written language, a movie with no written or spoken language, compiled, obfuscated, or minified code sample, and the like. In cases in which a language tag is not required, such as HTML, I would normally simply omit any language tag rather than using `zxx`.

Comment: Makes sense, but I think there's a gray area there. Yes, it'd be against the "spirit" of the spec to use something like `x-ruby`. Yet `x-...` is "defined solely by private agreement" (cf. BCP47) and it doesn't by itself "shadow" any previous primary language tags, so it'd be OK just not entirely kosher. My understanding is that it'd be the same as writing `en-x-ruby` in a document that's already `en`. With no lang attr, the text would implicitly be seen as plain `en`, which isn't quite right either. (This is a purely academic discussion by the way - I'm using class names :)

Comment: After narrowing down my choice of JS highlighter to either Prism or Rainbow, I initially chose the latter for what I _thought_ was its reasonable use of the `data-` attribute (errr… and the innumerable css themes). After reading more (including this post) I'm now veering back to the syntactically-correct Prism, with classnames.

Comment: How would I specify `lang`/`style` to C# in github `<pre><code>` for highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a better way than to misuse the `lang` attribute with the `zzx` prefix you mention (interesting find by the way!). The `type` attribute *might* be slightly more fitting, but it of course isn't valid in `pre` elements.

By the way, [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/code) (W3C reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-CODE)) might be more fitting than `<pre>`:

> The HTML Code Element (`<code>`) represents a fragment of computer code. By default, it is displayed in the browser's default monospace font.

Comment: Yes, `<code lang="...">` would be very precise, semantically speaking. But it's also an inline element, so for longer runs of source code (which was the only thing on my mind when I wrote the question), I'd still use `<pre>`, I think. I've updated my question with a note about all this – thanks a lot!